# Delete contacts from Experience profile

Tags: experience-profile

How can we delete all contacts from **Experience Profile** using PowerShell script?

Version: **Sitecore 9.1.1**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far I know it doesn't exist any commandlets that would wrap the Mongo/xDB APIs.

But you can use another module to delete xdb contacts: **https://marketplace.sitecore.net/en/Modules/Analytics_Database_Manager.aspx**

Comment: Found a blog to remove contacts using SQl commands: https://andypaz.com/2019/11/27/delete-xdb-contacts/. But Sitecore support confirmed they haven't tested this solution.